# Android support different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am fairly new to Android development. I am developing mobile app with Xamarin. I'm trying to understand on how do I go about supporting different screen sizes that holds background image?

My Original image file has a size of 7360px x 4912px @300dpi but likewise this dimension is probably too big for mobile screen. So my question is, what dimension do I need to set in order for the background image to be wrapped within the screen for different sizes?

and how do i organise the asset file in solution folder i.e. Layout folder for each sizes?

Comment: See [Creating Resources for Varying Screens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/resources-for-varying-screens?tabs=vswin) It should help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html